# What is meant by "timeout" in toastr.options

Tags: toastr

I searched alot on Internet but I could not found the description of `timeOut` and `extendedTimeOut` in `toastr.options`

```
toastr.option = {
showDuration : its the time the toastr is visible. 
timeOut : ??  (I need help here from you guys)
extendedTimeOut : ?? (I need help here from you guys)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How long the toast will display without user interaction

```
toastr.options.timeOut = 30;
```

How long the toast will display after a user hovers over it

```
toastr.options.extendedTimeOut = 60;
```

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#timeouts